# Cannot declare field <Object name> to be of abstract type

Tags: c++, object, virtual, declaration, abstract

Here is the error I am receiving and need help resolving...

```
g++ -g -c -std=c++11 main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
Executive.h:18:25: error: cannot declare field 'Executive::queue' to be of abstract type 'ListQueue<std::basic_string<char> >'
  ListQueue<std::string> queue;
                         ^
In file included from Executive.h:12:0,
                 from main.cpp:3:
ListQueue.h:8:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'ListQueue<std::basic_string<char> >':
 class ListQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType>
   ^
```

I'm not used to using "virtual" classes or even C++ for that matter, still learning, but I'm having trouble compiling my code as it is now. The virtual classes were provided by the instructor, so I'm just going to post the header files for my Executive, ListQueue, and ArrayStack classes. ListQueue and ArrayStack are the classes related to their "virtual" QueueInterface and StackInterface classes.

Executive.h

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include "ListQueue.h"
#include "ArrayStack.h"

class Executive
{
private:
    ListQueue<std::string> queue;
    ArrayStack<std::string> stack;
    std::string serving = "no one";
    std::string waiting = "no one";
    bool isWaiting = false;
    bool wasVIP = false;
    bool servingVIP = false;
public:

    /** Constructor reads in input file */
    Executive(std::istream& inputFile);

    /** Reads in and interprets the text file */
    void read(std::istream& is);

    /** Shows that the person currently being served finishes and the person waiting begins */  
    void done();

    /** Shows who is currently being served and who is next */
    void show();
};
```

ListQueue.h

```
 #include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

template<class ItemType>
class ListQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType>
{
private:    
    Node<ItemType>* first; //front of queue
    Node<ItemType>* last; //end of queue

public:
    ListQueue();             // Default constructor
    bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    void enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
    void dequeue() throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
    ItemType peekFront() const throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
}; // end ListQueue
```

ArrayStack.h

```
    #include "StackInterface.h"

const int MAX_STACK = 10;

template<class ItemType>
class ArrayStack : public StackInterface<ItemType>
{
private:    
    ItemType items[MAX_STACK]; // Array of stack items
    int      top;              // Index to top of stack

public:
    ArrayStack();             // Default constructor
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void push(const ItemType& newEntry) throw (PrecondViolatedExcep);
    void pop() throw (PrecondViolatedExcep);
    ItemType peek() const throw (PrecondViolatedExcep);
}; // end ArrayStack
```

StackInterface

```
template<typename ItemType>
class StackInterface
{
public:
   /** Sees whether this stack is empty.
    @return True if the stack is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Adds a new entry to the top of this stack.
    @pre a push is possible
    @post If the operation was successful, newEntry is at the top of the stack.
    @param newEntry The object to be added as a new entry. */
   virtual void push(const ItemType& newEntry)
        throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;

    /** Removes the top of this stack.
    @pre The stack is not empty.
    @post If the operation was successful, the top of the stack
    has been removed. */
   virtual void pop()
        throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;

   /** Returns the top of this stack.
    @pre The stack is not empty.
    @post The top of the stack has been returned, and
    the stack is unchanged.
    @return The top of the stack. */
   virtual ItemType peek() const throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
}; // end StackInterface
```

QueueInterface

```
template<typename ItemType>
class QueueInterface
{
public:
   /** Sees whether this queue is empty.
    @return True if the queue is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Adds a new entry to the back of this queue.
    @pre an enqueue is possible
    @post If the operation was successful, newEntry is at the 
       back of the queue.
    @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry. */
   virtual void enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry)
        throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;

    /** Removes the front of this queue.
     @pre The queue is not empty.
     @post If the operation was successful, the front of the queue 
       has been removed. */
   virtual void dequeue()
        throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;

   /** Returns the front of this queue.
    @pre The queue is not empty.
    @post The front of the queue has been returned, and the
       queue is unchanged.
    @return The front of the queue. */
   virtual ItemType peekFront() const
        throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
}; // end QueueInterface
```

Comment: All of the methods that are outlined in QueueInterface are also defined in ListQueue. I can post the interfaces if you would like, but there's really any change.

Comment: The functions in `ListQueue` are DECLARED but not DEFINED (implemented). The ones that are virtual with a `= 0` after the declaration are pure virtual and you cannot instantiate a class with pure virtual functions. However, you CAN declare a pointer to an abstract type. Changing the offending code to `ListQueue<std::string>* queue;` is the first step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot declare queue to be of type List<std::string> you can make it a pointer to abstract type ListQueue<std::string>. Same with the stack.

```
class Executive
{
        private:
    ListQueue<std::string> *queue;
    ArrayStack<std::string> *stack;
    std::string serving = "no one";
    std::string waiting = "no one";
    bool isWaiting = false;
    bool wasVIP = false;
    bool servingVIP = false;
public:
}
```

The reason you cannot do that is that if it is not a pointer, the compiler has to determine the shape in memory of your new class, it needs to know things like what size that the types of the fields in your class definition are. I however cannot do this for an abstract class, since it is not a complete definition. If you make it a pointer to an abstract class that it can figure out since pointers are just a integer.

---

After talking with you a bit I realize the mistake. You are inheriting interfaces your teacher gave you. This is a tool when you write code to give other people a contract that says build me something that will do what I want and this this the way I will use it.

The interface definition your professor gave you are empty, there is no logic that defines that the functions should do. Your classes are supposed to inherit his interfaces, which you have done, but you classes are also supposed to fill in the details for all the methods.

For example:

```
#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

template<class ItemType>
class ListQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType>
{
private:    
    Node<ItemType>* first; //front of queue
    Node<ItemType>* last; //end of queue

public:
    ListQueue();             // Default constructor
    bool isEmpty() const
    {
       // add logic here that will determine if the queue is empty.
    }

    void enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) throw (PrecondViolatedExcep)
    {
       // Add logic to add element to queue
    }

    void dequeue() throw (PrecondViolatedExcep)
    {
       // add  logic to remove element from queue
    }

    ItemType peekFront() const throw (PrecondViolatedExcep)
    {
       // add logic to look at next element in queue without removing it.
    }

}; // end ListQueue
```

Once you have filled out the logic for those interfaces your class will now be fully defined and you can use it. You are not restricted to those methods you can add helper methods if you like and constructors, destructors etc.. but you MUST implement at least the set that is part of the interface.

Makes sense?

Does that make sense.

Comment: Yeah, the stack object was a pointer because I tried this earlier and forgot to change that one back... I was getting seg faults

Comment: Did you initialize your queue and stack before using them? In any case you will have to create a non abstract class that inherits the ListQueue and ArrayStack if you want to actually create an instance that you can use.

Comment: What do you mean by initialize? That's what I thought I was doing with the objects, but now they're initialized as pointers. Executive has a #include "ListQueue.h" and "ArrayStack.h" already, can I just change that to inheritance somehow?

Comment: No.. I think that you did not intend to make the ListQueue and ArrayStack classes abstract. You need to remove the =0 at the end of the functions and add the body to the abstract function you inherited from the stack and queue interfaces.

Comment: You do not need to make queue and stack pointers if you change the declaration of ListQueue and ArrayStack so that they are no longer abstract and provide a definition (body) for the missing functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by missing functions, I'll post the interfaces so you can see, but I think they are all defined.

Comment: @Rob I saw your answer now -_-

Comment: The interface define the the function signature, what its name is what the arguments are but not what it does.. Lets take the isEmpty() method. It is supposed to return a bool. But there is no logic there that does anything in the interface hence the =0 it tell the compiler don't worry about it I am just an interface. Someone else will have to inherit me and provide the logic that return true when the Queue is empty and false when it is not. In this case your class will have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`Executive.h:18:25: error: cannot declare field 'Executive::queue' to be of abstract type 'ListQueue<std::basic_string<char> >'
  ListQueue<std::string> queue;`

It seems like the class `QueueInterface` is an abstract class. In order to use it you have derived the `ListQueue` class out of it.

But the `ListQueue` class has the following:

```
bool isEmpty() const = 0;
void enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
void dequeue() throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
ItemType peekFront() const throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
```

Which makes it abstract as well.

Any method in a C++ class with an `= 0` at the end makes it a **pure virtual method** and the class an **abstract class**.

Now abstract classes cant be instantiated. This is because, the it's behavior is not known (the definition of the pure virtual function doesn't exist)

Look at the following example:

```
class Mammal
{
    public:
        virtual void breath() = 0;
}
```

Now something like `Mammal m` throws an error. Why? To understand this, just consider the following code:

```
// Assume the below line doesn't throw an error
Mammal m;

// m is now an object of type Mammal
m.breath();
```

What can you expect from the line `m.breath()` ? It doesn't have a definition and the compiler gets absolutely no idea as to what is to be executed. That's the reason it doesn't work.

What do I do then?
Derive a class out of the `Mammal` (abstract) class

```
class Horse : public Mammal
{
    public:
        void breath();
}

void Horse::breath()
{
    // Code for horse breathing
}
```

So here the `breath()` is defined (i.e. the mammal's breathing behavior is defined)
I can now do something like:

```
Horse h;
h.breath();
```

and it'll work!

If you want to know the point of having an abstract class, it's because I can have many classes of base type `Mammal` as follows:

```
class Dog : public Mammal
{
    public:
        void breath()
        {
            // Dog's breathing code
        }
}

class Cat : public Mammal
{
    public:
        void breath()
        {
            // Cat's breathing code
        }
}
```

and then I can do something like:

```
// represents a generic mammal i.e it can be either a horse, a dog or a cat, that I can decide at run time
Mammal* m;

int i = 0;
cin >> i;
switch(i)
{
    case 0:
        m = new Horse();
    case 1:
        m = new Dog();
    case 2:
        m = new Cat();
    default:
        m = 0;
}

if(m!=0)
{
    m->breath();
    delete m;
}
```

So that way you can call the appropriate breath() at run-time

So I guess you've got an idea as to what you're supposed to do:
Define your the method definition of your sub-classes (`ListQueue` in your case)

Comment: Like the dog Breath example :).